# Why am I not able to iterate through my record in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, record

Given the following record in AppleScript:

```
set usergroup to {user1:{name:"Darth Vader", role:"leader"}, user2:{name:"Yoda", role:"instructor"}}
```

to display a specific user I can:

```
set trainer to get user1 of usergroup
display dialog (name of trainer)
```

but if I want to display all users I try:

```
repeat with x from 1 to (length of usergroup)
    set member to ("user" & x) as item
    display dialog member
end repeat
```

and I get `user1` and `user2` but if I try:

```
repeat with x from 1 to (length of usergroup)
    set member to ("user" & x) as item
    display dialog (get name of member) as text
end repeat
```

I get an error so I tried:

```
repeat with x from 1 to (length of usergroup)
    set member to (get name of ("user" & x)) as item
    display dialog member as text
end repeat
```

Why am I not able to get `name` of the users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the class of the `member` variable is a string, not a key.

For a record which contains a simple list of users : use `someRecord as list`

```
set usergroup to {user1:{name:"Darth Vader", role:"leader"}, user2:{name:"Yoda", role:"instructor"}}
repeat with member in (usergroup as list) -- the member variable contains a record
    display dialog (name of member)
    --display dialog (role of member)
end repeat
```

---

Or, you can use the `run script` command to evaluate a string ("user" & x)  as a key

```
set usergroup to {user1:{name:"Darth Vader", role:"leader"}, user2:{name:"Yoda", role:"instructor"}}
repeat with x from 1 to (length of usergroup)
    set member to ("user" & x)
    set thisMemberName to run script "on run {thisRecord}" & linefeed & "name of " & member & " of thisRecord" & linefeed & "end run" with parameters {usergroup}
    display dialog thisMemberName
end repeat
```